# Are the tags (bookmark) and (chat-bookmarks) intended for the same purpose?

Tags: discussion, tags, chat

I was looking for something about bookmarking conversations in chat and I have noticed that the questions I found were tagged either by [conversation](/questions/tagged/conversation) or by [bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark) or by [chat-bookmarks](/questions/tagged/chat-bookmarks). Only the last one has [tag-excerpt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279675/revisions) and [tag-wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279674/revisions).

The three tags seem to me very similar, at least (bookmark) and (chat-bookmarks) seem to be used for the same purpose, when I look at the questions currently having these tags. To me the name (chat-bookmarks) seem definitely better than (bookmark), since it is much less ambiguous. (Bookmark has more general meaning and I found questions in this tag like [Can I bookmark a question on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23670/can-i-bookmark-a-question-on-stack-overflow) or [Bookmarklet: Show unanswered questions (0-answer, not no-accepted-answer)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31653/bookmarklet-show-unanswered-questions-0-answer-not-no-accepted-answer) which have nothing to do with chat.)

The tag (conversation) contains similar questions. Although not all question which have this tag at the moment are chat related.

I think that having good tags improves possibility to search for questions about some topic. So I am asking for advice what to do with these closely related tags?

- Should (bookmark) be completely removed and replaced by (chat-bookmarks) in those questions which are about chat? Or should we create a synonym [bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark) → [chat-bookmarks](/questions/tagged/chat-bookmarks)?
- What about [conversation](/questions/tagged/conversation)? Should this tag stay separate? Or would it be reasonable if it was also a synonym?

Comment: Well, bookmark is more general and can be used for browser bookmarks or even favorite questions. It's quite a mess, need to go over the questions and see if it can be removed. That's why I created the [tag:chat-bookmarks] tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard what's your take on making [meta-tag:conversation] synonym of [meta-tag:chat-bookmarks]?

Comment: [tag:conversation] and [tag:chat-bookmarks] refer to different things don't they?

Comment: @Cai It depends on what you mean by conversation. But the thing you get when you bookmark something in chat [is called conversation](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=conversations) here at SE. (And if you look at questions in that tag, the tags is mostly used for conversations in chat. With a few exceptions, like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176829/how-to-pull-a-conversation-from-facebook-to-stackoverflow).)

Comment: @Martin you are right, I was thinking chat-bookmark was referring to starred messages in chat, not bookmarked conversations. It's early and I'm tired...

Comment: @Cali Yes, [stars](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=stars) and bookmarked conversations are different thing. As it turns out, there is even a separate ([tag:chat-stars]) tag.

Comment: As I said, it is quite a mess now. No doubt it needs some reordering and retagging, but I don't think that synonyms are the answer. @gnat.

Answer (score 5):

I'm bumping this to specifically support synonymizing [conversation](/questions/tagged/conversation) to [chat-bookmarks](/questions/tagged/chat-bookmarks). The recent usage of [conversation](/questions/tagged/conversation) (the last 7 of its 10 questions, or all since Dec. '11) are all about chat bookmarks. The tag excerpts are basically identical as well:

[conversation](/questions/tagged/conversation)

> For questions about the chat conversation feature (chronological thread of chat messages that you can select, give a title to, and share).

[chat-bookmarks](/questions/tagged/chat-bookmarks)

> This tag is for questions about the chat conversation bookmark feature found on the conversation tab on the chatroom info page

As for the other three [conversation](/questions/tagged/conversation) questions, [these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96756/cant-move-discussion-to-chat-with-scroll-wheel) [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96493/can-we-have-customized-verbose-descriptive-automatically-move-this-discussion) would be better tagged [move-to-chat](/questions/tagged/move-to-chat), and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29833/are-updates-to-questions-and-answers-problematic) would benefit from [edits](/questions/tagged/edits).

Thus I think we should synonymize [conversation](/questions/tagged/conversation) → [chat-bookmarks](/questions/tagged/chat-bookmarks) to **reflect current usage**, after retagging [conversation](/questions/tagged/conversation)'s three oldest questions.

Comment: Funnily enough, I've just obtained the "Create Tag Synonyms" privilege - not that it would help here, since I don't have score in either tag.

Answer (score 3):

I asked one of those questions (a few years ago) and I think I would have used [chat-bookmarks](/questions/tagged/chat-bookmarks) if it had been suggested.  So either the tag didn't exist yet or I used a tag auto-suggestion (if that feature existed then), most likely.  I'm not saying this to defend the use of the tag but to explain why some of those other questions might have the [bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark) tag instead of [chat-bookmark](/questions/tagged/chat-bookmark).

I suggest retagging the [bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark) questions that are really about chat.  If there are any questions left that are about bookmarks but not chat bookmarks, and we decide the tag is valuable, then we rename the tag to be more descriptive (and give it a meaningful wiki excerpt).  If we mean [browser-bookmarks](/questions/tagged/browser-bookmarks), for example, say that.  This way a user trying to tag a question will see two specific types of bookmarks, increasing the chances of tags being used as intended.

If we decide we don't need a bookmarks-but-not-chat-bookmarks tag, then we don't need to create the synonym.  Usually pure-substring synonyms aren't helpful; the real tag shows up when you start to type, even if what you're typing isn't from the beginning of the tag.  (I just tested this.)  [chat-bookmarks](/questions/tagged/chat-bookmarks) will show up when somebody starts to type "bookmark".